# Invoice sending as email with PDF attachment replaces email contents with PDF contents

Tags: civicontribute, invoice, attachments

Sending invoices with emails, where the invoice is attached as PDF to the email, and having a freely designed email text results in the contents of the email body being replaced with the contents of the invoice PDF and nothing being attached to the email.

We used the normal emailing invoice workflow and have tested it on CiviCRM 5.57.1, 5.58.1 and 5.60.0 with either Drupal 9.5.1 or 9.5.5.

How to reproduce:
First search for a contribution for which you want to send the invoice. Select the ones you want to send in the search result. Choose the action "Invoices - print or email". On the next screen select "Email Invoice" and fill the now displayed fields with suitable data. We normally use the Invoice Helper extension but the problem also appears without the extension being enabled.
Enter some subject and some content for the email. Then press send and check the received email(s).

The content of the received email(s) is that of the invoice that should be attached. The entered email content is gone.
The invoice template has not been altered and is in default state.

We discovered this problem with the mentioned CiviCRM version but we do not know with which version this behavior started. The invoice sending worked before.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Just noting this appeared to fix for the reporter & one other

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4259#note_90528

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you hit something you think is a regression please create a ticket in gitlab & indicate you believe it is a regression. We prioritise possible regressions (& accept that some false positives will be reported)